# Iterating through multiple file upload fields

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-file-upload

I have a directive that essentially populates multiple individual input file fields, with other HTML form elements. The mechanism itself is done through auto-population an array with the number of elements, which is pushed/popped as more file fields are added. This itself, drives an array with a numerical list, that is ideally supposed to alter the name/id of each element (this also doesn't work, the presence of the { in the attributes causes a script-breaking syntax error).

```
<div ng-controller="MultiFileUpload">
    <form ng-submit="file_upload_multiple()" novalidate>
    <div class="upload_fields">
        <fieldset ng-repeat="Item in FileUploadItems">
        <input type="file" name="upload_file" id="upload_file_{{Item}}" ngf-select ng-model="filename_{{Item}}" ngf-max-size="2MB" required />
        <input type="text" name="filename" id="filename_{{Item}}" required/>
        <select name="filetype" id='filetype_{{Item}}' required>
            <option label="" value=""></option>
            <option label="Example Document 1" value="example_doc_1">Example 1</option>
            <option label="Example Document 2" value="example_doc_2">Example 2</option>
        </select>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <button>Save Files</button>
</div>
```

When the submit is fired, I am not clear on the best mechanism to have the client-side script iterate through all the available fields as a distinct group. having the template variable call in the name/id is a major throwoff, and If I can accomplish a solution that scales upward without this eyesore, that would be great. I already have an idea on how I'll eventually stash all the field data (through iterative POST REST calls -- i'm working with a very out of date API), but getting to that step requires determining the best approach to process multiple field entries. Any suggestions?

I should clarify, I am using ng-form-upload to assist in the task of interfacing with the data in the file input fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an array to store your model something like this:

```
<div ng-controller="MultiFileUpload" ng-init="files = [{}]">
    <form ng-submit="file_upload_multiple()" novalidate>
    <div class="upload_fields" ng-repeat="fileData in files">
        <fieldset ng-repeat="Item in FileUploadItems">
        <input type="file" name="upload_file" ngf-select ng-model="fileData.file" ngf-max-size="2MB" required />
        <input type="text" name="filename" ng-model="fileData.name" required/>
        <select name="filetype" ng-model="fileData.type" required>
            <option label="" value=""></option>
            <option label="Example Document 1" value="example_doc_1">Example 1</option>
            <option label="Example Document 2" value="example_doc_2">Example 2</option>
        </select>
        </fieldset>
    </div>

    <button>Save Files</button>
</div>
```

Then to add another set of fields you can push an empty object into files and the files array will contains all the data that is needed to be submitted.

Comment: I still don't see how any of the changes to the altered field would be exposed either in files[{}] or in the ng-submit method. From my implementation so far, it still treats files[] as an empty array, only with multiple entries. Can you clarify this part of the logic?

Comment: Nevermind, it was a syntax error. Thanks for the response!